# RadGrid Row Reordering on client side

Tags: telerik, radgrid

Does anyone have any idea how to perform rows reordering for Telerik RadGrid on ClientSide?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.reorderColumns(lastColumnName, firstColumnName);` in Javascript.

See the demo at: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/resizing/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: The initial question was regarding the rows. Your answer is about columns reordering

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing this post, Telerik doesn't have pure client side reordering that I'm aware of, it's only client-side with a postback: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/draganddrop/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: @moontear at the time of writing, they didn't :-)